# Problems installing Team Foundation Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We are trying to install TFS 2012 with our version of VS 2008. We have installed Team Explorer and VS 2008 SP1. We have set up a group and admin users but cannot create a new project. When we right click on our Team Explorer project and select New Team Project, we get the following error.

TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of Team Explorer. Contact your project administrator ...

Neither of those conditions apply as we have the required permissions and have installed the latest version of Team Explorer.

If anyone has experienced this or knows how to resolve this problem, please let us know as we cant continue without seeting up a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create TeamProjects in TFS2012 you need to run TeamExplorer2012 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/05/permission-error-with-creating-a-team-project-from-vs-2010-on-tfs-11-beta.aspx)

Comment: We have downloaded TeamExplorer2012 and VS2008 SP1 and yet we get the same TF30172 error every time we try to add a new project, Help!!

Comment: Are you using TeamExplorer2012 in Visual Studio 2012? (it is installed with TeamExplorer2012) If you work in Visual Studio 2008, you use TeamExplorer2008 with compatibility update for TFS2012. If you are working in Visual Studio 2012 and get this message, are you sure you are ProjectCollectionAdministrator?

Comment: No we are using Visual Studio 2008 and have downloaded TFS 2012 and TeamExplorer2012. We have tried the compatibility update and that has not worked either, we still get the TF30172 error.

Comment: Right, you need to install TeamExplorer2012, which will also install a Visual Studio2012. Start Visual Studio2012 and connect to your TFS and create the TeamProject you need. There is no way to do it in Visual Studio 2008.